# Nothing shown on doing npm start for react-app

Tags: reactjs

I made a sample application using create-react-app and on doing `npm start`, it showed me the default react js page. I then edited app.js inside src to

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

but this shows a blank page on doing `npm start`. I checked and there was a `<div id="root">` in index.html already. So why is this showing a blank page?

I have checked the console and it shows 2 errors:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it. I was editing App.js inside src(because it was mentioned on default react page) while I needed to edit Index.js for that example to run , or do something like

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () =>{
    return (<h1>Hello, world!</h1>);
};

export default App;
```

and this would make the required changes in index.js .